# Change contents of cell where formatting cells doesn't assist

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a cell with the data in it in the format of 01/07/2012  6:58:13 AM

However I would like the date only, I have tried to Format Cells and select the format I want 01/07/2012 but the time still remains.

How can i get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure Excel really threads it as a number/date and not text? I.e. is it left or right aligned? If right aligned, you need to first convert it to a date (e.g. by using the VALUE function in the column next to it).

Comment: @PeterAlbert Its to the right so its text. The value Function still kept it as text and the DateValue(A1) just causes a vlaue error.

Comment: sorry, my bad: if it's right aligned its a number, left aligned is a text (assuming that the cell's alignment isn't formatted otherwise).

Thus, it should be a number - if you do `=A1+1` in the cell next to it, do you get the date+1d or a Value error?

Also, is, the format of the date the same as your local format, i.e. do you have an English system with English locale settings? If not, you might need to adjust this in your system settings so Excel knows its a date...

Comment: @PeterAlbert yes its a number and we use English locales.

Comment: If it's a number, how do you change the Date format?
If the default format is not working for some reasons, what happens if you set it to the custom format `MM/DD/YYYY'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date for some reasons is stored as text (e.g. you're using a non-English system), you can parse the text and convert it to a proper date with the following function: `=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))`

If you have an English system (it might also work on other locales, just give it a try), you don't have to parse the text, but simply convert it with this formula: `=--A1` (and format the cell as Date).

Comment: No that formula just produces an incorrect date with a time so 01/07/2012  7:02:32 AM becomes 10/08/2911 0:00 when I just want the date

Comment: The reason it gives this strange result is that your cell is already stored as a number - the answer is only working if it's text.